# Deserialize JSON encoded HTML code with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, html, json, system.text.json

I'm using C# to call a REST API which returns a JSON object containing HTML code. Here is an example of the object I'm interested in

```
{    
    "Body": "<html class=\"sg-campaigns\"><head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"><meta content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1\"><meta content=\"IE=Edge\"><style type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody ..."
}
```

I would like to further process the HTML code but since it contains various elements to be a valid JSON string deserialization with `System.Text.Json` fails with the following exception

```
System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: '<' is an invalid start of a value.
```

I have tried using the following code to deserialize the content of the Body attribute

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping,
    WriteIndented = true
};

var content = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<String>(html, options);
```

The elements causing errors are for example:

- `\ "`
- `< !--`
- `\r`, `\n`, `\t`

I'm curious to learn how the `Body` attribute from the code above can be cleaned to only contain valid HTML, maybe someone from the community has an idea about this.

Comment: Have you try to use Encoding and Decoding???

Comment: thanks for your reply! yes i have tried using JsonSerializerOptions with Encoder settings. I have updated my question with the info

Comment: Have you tried escaping the carriage return(`\\r`), tab(`\\t`) and newline(`\\n`) characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a simple object that contains a `Body` property (and any other properties  you're going to use):

```
internal class ResponseObject
{
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize the response JSON to that type of object instead of `String`.:

```
var content = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseObject>(html, options);
```

`Content.Body` will contain the decoded HTML.

Comment: i feel stupid now  what an easy solution. Thank you very much.